# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PostsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tags_attributes

Track:

```
activemodel (3.2.9) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
activemodel (3.2.9) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
activemodel (3.2.9) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
activemodel (3.2.9) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:216:in `block in update_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:65:in `block in update'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:270:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:270:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:194:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:64:in `update'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__3328307413760429839__process_action__1872096882865630313__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__208513489912999818__call__4048539670769559606__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/tater/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/tater/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/tater/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

How can i fix it？i study ruby on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're used this in `Post` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
```

So, add this in your `Post` model:

```
attr_accessible :tags_attributes
```

More info here [Nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: i have not "accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags ",but add "attr_accessible :tags_attributes" is fix the problem~

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add

```
# model.rb
attr_accessible :name_of_attributes, :seperated_by_commas, :like_these_here
```